# Как задать разные Activity для разных flavor'ов?

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

Есть требование - в зависимости от типа сборки запускать 2 разные `Activity`.

В `build.gradle` имеется следующее:

```
productFlavors {
            flavor1 {
               manifestPlaceholders = [ mainActivity:".ui.activities.Activity1"]
            }
            flavor2 {
                manifestPlaceholders = [ mainActivity:".ui.activities.Activity2"]
}
```

А в `AndroidManifest.xml` следующее:

```
...
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="${mainActivity}" //<<<что то тут не так
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
...
```

AS выделяет красным, сообщая о том что не знает что это за путь и при запуске приложения отображается ошибка.

Возможно ли как нибудь для разных флаворов определить разные стартовые `Activity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошим вариантом будет назвать эти `Activity` одинаково и положить в папки `flavor1` и `flavor2`, никаких `manifestPlaceholders` не понадобится.

Если имена `Activity` должны быть разными, можно сделать два разных манифеста и так же разложить их по папкам.